# In django,How to read form data, perform operation and then store in database?

Tags: python, django, forms, view, models

This is my model:

```
class Expense(models.Model):   
     Item= models.CharField(max_length=100)
     description= models.CharField(max_length=1000)
     Amount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2, default=0)
     date = models.DateField(default=date.today())
     category = models.ForeignKey(ExpenseCategory) # either expense or income
```

I want to write a code to read the the values from textarea on html form as

```
"Vegitable 10kg 100 Taxi 10kms 200 mobile  brothers 200  clothes 2shirts 1500.50"
```

then i will split this into different list as (i have written code for this):

```
item=[vegitable,Taxi,mobile,clothes]
description = [10kg,10kms,brothes,2shirts]
amount=[100,200,200,1500.50]
```

Now i want to want to write a code to store above lists  (of 04 records) alongwith date and category ,into above model( actually database). The database must look like as below.

```
Item        description Amount    date     category
____________________________________________________
Vegitable    10kg        100    28/09/2014   expense
Taxi         10kms       200    28/09/2014   expense 
mobile       brothers    200    28/09/2014   expense
clothes      2shirts    1500.50 28/09/2014   expense
```

Note: here date will be todays date and category will be expense

Answer (score 1):

After some proper python formatting the data looks like this:

```
item=['vegitable','Taxi','mobile','clothes']
amount=[100,200,200,1500.50]
description = ['10kg','10kms','brothes','2shirts']
```

To rearrange the data according to your model:

```
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal as D

category = ExpenseCategory.objects.get(name='expense')

rows = map(lambda i,a,d: {'Item':i, 'Amount':D(a), 'description':d}, item, amount, description)

for row in rows:
    expense = Expense(**row)
    expense.category = category
    expense.date = datetime.datetime.now()
    expense.save()
```

UPDATE:

The integration depends on your form handling:

Put the formatting of the data at `Form.clean`:

```
class ExpensesForm(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ExpensesForm, self).clean()
        # Your code for splitting things up goes here
        cleaned_data['expenses'] = map(lambda i,a,d: {'Item':i, 'Amount':D(a), 'description':d}, item, amount, description)
        return cleaned_data
```

At your view you may do sth. like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid()
        for row in form.cleaned_data['expenses']:
            expense = Expense(**row)
            expense.category = category
            expense.date = datetime.datetime.now()
            expense.save()
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...... can u please tell me where to insert this code..... I am newbie in django..... I am thankful for ur valuable thought and time.....

Comment: Every this is fine row has proper data but database is not updated :(

Comment: is_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' ........ this is the error i m  getting

Comment: Thanks a lot @tc77 i have finally completed the task ihave written a seperate answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    category = ExpenseCategory.objects.get(description='expense')
    # code for split
    str=self.description
    lis=str.split()
    description=lis[0::3]
    item=lis[1::3]
    amount=lis[2::3]


    rows = map(lambda d,a: {'description':d,'amount':D(a)}, description, amount )

    for row in rows:
        print("I am in start of for")
        expense = Expense(**row)
        expense.category = category
        expense.date = self.date
        print("%s %s %s %s" % (self.description, self.amount,self.category,self.date))
        print("%s %s %s %s" % (expense.description, expense.amount,expense.category,expense.date))
        expense.save()
        #super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method
        super(Expense, expense).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method
        print("I am in end of for")
```

The above code I have written in models.py